# Google games services rest sign in https redirect error

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

On my site I am using google play games services to sign in and I want to redirect to an https site but when I am signing in with https set as redirect url and click allow the sign in screen freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow this steps that is stated in the Google Play Games [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#modifying_client_id_related_attributes) that to modify attributes related to your OAuth 2.0 client ID (web origins and redirect urls for a web app, bundle ID for an iOS app, etc.)

1. Open the Google Play Developer Console and navigate to your game.
2. On the **Game Details** page, scroll to the bottom and click the link to the linked Google Developers Console project.
3. In the Google Developers Console, select your project.
4. In the sidebar on the left, select **APIs & auth**. Make sure that the Google Play Games Services API status is *ON* in the displayed list of APIs.
5. In the sidebar on the left, select **Registered apps**.
6. Expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section and find the attribute to edit.

Also make sure you follow the steps in [Creating Client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [Configure Service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring).